# JasperReports: error in case using subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jdeveloper

I have 5 *jrxml* files, some of them have *subreport*. I use them from *JDeveloper*. I have not any problem with the report that have not *subreport*. But when I use the reports that have *subreport* I get this error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluateText(JRFillTextField.j
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementC
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFill
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.j
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFil
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.j
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.ja
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportR
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I'm using *iReport 4.0.2*

Comment: May be something wrong with you templates

Answer (score 0):

It's null pointer - it means that your subreport reffers to a variable/object that is not initiated yet. If this variable/object would be just plain empty - it would generate subreport with empty fields, but this error you're having means, that you want to put in subreport infromations from not existing source. Check your project, and erase this data, or initialize them in your code before creating report.